# read otp from seetest mobile application and paste to continue with login process in web application

Tags: appium, cucumber, eclipse, maven, seetest

I am using cucumber and configure appium and seetest to run web application on mobile browser, i want to check otp that is sent via my application to mobile number (on seetest device number which is i am using currently) and read otp then back to my application which is open in chrome mobile browser and paste that otp here and continue.

Comment: OTP = One Time Password?

Comment: ...and what's the problem? Your question sounds like it's something you want to do, but haven't tried or encountered an issue yet?